# How would you solve for a function when given only the relationships between its transformations?

Tags: functions, recreational-mathematics, functional-equations

By that I mean, if you're given  $f(x+3)=2f(x)$ is true for all x, is there some way to find out f(x), and if so, how would one go about doing that?  And if it's not possible, why?

Comment: With that information alone?  No.  You would further need information about all values of $f(x)$ along some interval like $[0,3)$.

Comment: What if you knew all the discrete values of the function for all positive integers, and all that mattered for the function were the positive integers including 0?

Comment: Per the comment of @JMoravitz, just to take an extreme example: define $~f(x) = x^{x} : x ~$ rational, $~0 \leq x < 3.$  Then, for the same function $f(x)$, define $f(x) = e^x : x ~$ irrational, $~0 \leq x < 3.$  Then, the function $f(x)$ which is well defined on the interval $0 \leq x < 3$ can have its domain extended to include all real numbers, in accordance with the constraint in your posting.  This can similarly be done for any corresponding $f(x)$ defined on the interval $0 \leq x < 3.$

Comment: Then that still doesn't tell you anything about noninteger values of $x$.  Even further restricting it to have $f$ be continuous (*which you don't require in your original question*) that still doesn't tell you anything about the non-integer values.  Playing connect the dots, sure... you can put your pencil down on the first dot and try and draw a straight line to the next... but you could also draw a squiggle between them or a zigzag or any other shape.  Similarly there are *many* different functions with a particular value of $f(1)$ and $f(2)$

Comment: "*If you knew all the discrete values of the function and all that mattered were the positive integers*"... well then... you already know all the values of the function... If you know the function then you know the function, and there isn't a problem here at all.

Comment: It's not said anywhere but since you used linear-algebra tag, I assume those are linear functions. In this case f(x+3)=f(x)+f(3). Given that we can deduce that f(x)=f(3). The slope of this function is apparently zero, but the constant part is impossible to deduce

Comment: If linear, then $f(0) = f(0x)=0f(x)=0$.  Of course, that is surely not what op is askin for

Comment: Please don’t use tags you don’t understand. The linear algebra tag has no business here and confuses many people reading your question.

Comment: You should edit your Question's body to add context.  While you pose a problem that can be resolved by mathematical argument, you do not seem to have researched it before posting here, and you have not provided context of any kind.  Figuring why you asked then becomes a guessing game for Readers, not the kind of content Math.SE seeks to "collect and curate".  I'm voting to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you require continuity you can get an infinite number of solutions.

For each real number $c$,

$$ {f(x)=c(\sqrt[3]{2})^x} $$

is a solution since

\begin{eqnarray}
{f(x+3)}&=&{c(\sqrt[3]{2})^{x+3}}\\
&=&{c(\sqrt[3]{2})^x(\sqrt[3]{2})^3}\\
&=&{2c(\sqrt[3]{2})^x}\\
&=&{2f(x)}
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I used \large because the cube root is hard to read on some devices.

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)=0$ satisfies your definition.

So does the function  $$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
1,  & 0\le x<3 \\
2, & 3\le x<6 \\
4, & 6\le x<9 \\
8, & 9\le x<12 \\
16, & 12\le x<15 \\
...
\end{cases}$$

In fact, you can see how defining $f(x)$ to be whatever you want on the interval $[0,3)$ leads to a unique $f$ that satisfies $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}:f(x+3)=2f(x)$. But your equation does not uniquely define a function. In general, recursive definitions require some initial conditions for uniqueness.